# How can I filter through my groups/clusters to keep only the ones with different column2 values?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a file which looks something like this:

```
1   Ape 5138150 5140933
1   Ape 4289 7147
1   Ape 2680951 2683603
1   Ape 1484200 1486662
1   Baboon 3706008 3708636
1   Baboon 11745108 11747790
1   Baboon 3823683 3826474

2   Dog 216795245 216796748
2   Dog 14408 15922

3   Elephant 18 691
3   Ape 1 824

4   Frog 823145 826431
4   Sloth 35088 37788
4   Snake 1071033 1074121

5   Tiger 997421 1003284
5   Tiger 125725 131553

6   Tiger 2951524 2953649
6   Lion 178820 180879
```

Each group (or cluster) is indicated by the line number (e.g. all lines starting with 1 are in group 1) and different groups are separated by a blank line, as shown above. I'm interested in column 2. I want to keep all groups that have at least two different animals in column 2, but delete all groups that only have the one animal (i.e. species-specific groups). So with this file, I want to get rid of groups 2 and 5, but keep the others:

```
1   Ape 5138150 5140933
1   Ape 4289 7147
1   Ape 2680951 2683603
1   Ape 1484200 1486662
1   Baboon 3706008 3708636
1   Baboon 11745108 11747790
1   Baboon 3823683 3826474

3   Elephant 18 691
3   Ape 1 824

4   Frog 823145 826431
4   Sloth 35088 37788
4   Snake 1071033 1074121

6   Tiger 2951524 2953649
6   Lion 178820 180879
```

Is there a quick/easy way to do this? My actual file has over 10,000 different groups, so doing it manually is not a (sensible) option. I have a feeling I should be able to do this with awk, but no luck so far.

Comment: Does it have to be a bash/unix/awk-solution or is i.e. python acceptable as well?

Comment: Any solution would be great haha! I'm just a bit more familiar with bash than python, hence the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for `length(array)`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS="\n" }
{
    delete keys
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        split($i,f," ")
        keys[f[2]]
    }
}
length(keys) > 1

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1   Ape 5138150 5140933
1   Ape 4289 7147
1   Ape 2680951 2683603
1   Ape 1484200 1486662
1   Baboon 3706008 3708636
1   Baboon 11745108 11747790
1   Baboon 3823683 3826474

3   Elephant 18 691
3   Ape 1 824

4   Frog 823145 826431
4   Sloth 35088 37788
4   Snake 1071033 1074121

6   Tiger 2951524 2953649
6   Lion 178820 180879
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with python:

```
group = []
animals = set()

with open('data') as f:
    for l in f:
        line = l.strip()
        if line == '':
            if len(animals) > 1:
                for g in group:
                    print g
                print ''

            group = []
            animals = set()
            continue

        group.append(line)
        animals.add(line.split()[1])

if len(animals) > 1:
    for g in group:
        print g
```

`data` is the name of your input file.

Explanation:
Iterate over every line of the file.
If the line is not a blank line, we add the line to the group to being able to print it later. Also, we add the second column to the animals distinct set.
If it is a blank line, we check whether we had more than one animal in the group. In that case we print all the lines of the group. In any case, we reset the group and animals since we are starting a new group.
The lines outside of the loop are required to write the last group if it contains more than one animal and if the file does not end with a blank line.