# How can i filter groups in a file to only show me the different combinations of column 2 values?

Tags: python, bash, unix, awk

I have a file which looks something like this:

```
1   Ape 5138150 5140933
1   Ape 4289 7147
1   Ape 2680951 2683603
1   Ape 1484200 1486662
1   Baboon 3706008 3708636
1   Baboon 11745108 11747790
1   Baboon 3823683 3826474

2   Baboon 250 33
2   Ape 1 89

3   Elephant 18 691
3   Ape 1 824
3   Baboon 3000 4569

4   Frog 823145 826431
4   Sloth 35088 37788
4   Snake 1071033 1074121

6   Tiger 2951524 2953649
6   Lion 178820 180879
```

where column 1 shows the group number, and column 2 shows the different animals in that group. What I'm interested in is how many different combinations of animals I have in this file. So for example, I'd like to reduce group 1 down to `Ape, Baboon`, and then ignore group 2 (since the ape+baboon combination has already been seen), but keep group 3 (because this group includes elephant as well, and is hence different). So the output could look something like:

```
Ape, Baboon

Elephant, Ape, Baboon

Frog, Sloth, Snake

Tiger, Lion
```

If possible, it'd be nice to keep which group number these animal combinations come from too, but that's really not a priority! Any ideas on how I might do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note you asked something quite similar yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31017611/ may be good to show some code, probably the accepted solution there is a good starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on my solution to yesterdays question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31052080/1745001) and again using GNU awk for `length(array)`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS="\n"; OFS=", " }
{
    delete keys
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        split($i,f," ")
        keys[f[2]]
    }
}
length(keys) > 1 {
    i=0
    keyList=""
    for (key in keys) {
        keyList = keyList (++i>1?OFS:"") key
    }
    if (!seen[keyList]++) {
        print NR, keyList
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1, Ape, Baboon

3, Ape, Baboon, Elephant

4, Sloth, Snake, Frog

5, Lion, Tiger
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %groups;
$/ = "\n\n";

while (<>) {
    my %a = ();
    for my $f ( split /\n/ ) { $a{ (split /\s+/, $f)[1] } = 1 }
    $groups{ join ', ', sort keys %a } = 1;
}

print $_, "\n" for ( sort keys %groups );
```

Output:

```
Ape, Baboon
Ape, Baboon, Elephant
Frog, Sloth, Snake
Lion, Tiger
```